# How to start SymmetricDS service?

Tags: windows, windows-services, symmetricds

I opened "Services" and tried starting "SymmetricDS" service.

Then the system show dialog with below content:

---

"Windows could not start the symmetricds service on Local Computer.

Error 2 the system cannot find the file specified."

---

Then I opened "Registry Editor" and saw ImagePath like that:

"java" -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Webstercare\MedSig 4\Tools\synchronisation\SymmetricDS\tmp" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Webstercare\MedSig 4\Tools\synchronisation\SymmetricDS\lib\symmetric-wrapper.jar" init "C:\Program Files (x86)\Webstercare\MedSig 4\Tools\synchronisation\SymmetricDS\conf\sym_service.conf"

Please help me to start this service!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible your system can't find the "java" command on your system path, in which case you'd need to reinstall [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) or add the Java bin directory to your system PATH.

Are you able to run java from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

**If you can install the service but can't start it:**

```
PS <C:\Program Files\SymmDS\bin>> ./sym_service.bat start
Waiting for server to start
Error 19: StartService returned error 2: The system cannot find the file 
specified.
Native error 19
```

Another Symptom: Trying to start it via the task managers service tab gives you:

```
"The operation could not be completed. Access is denied."
```

Change ***wrapper.java.command*** to the full path to your java.exe in conf\sym_service.conf.

For example mine was:

```
# Java Runtime Executable
  wrapper.java.command=java
```

And I changed it to:

```
# Java Runtime Executable
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe
```

**If you can't install the service:**

Error: "the system cannot find the path specified" when you try to install the service.
It's probably a bad or out of date path for your environment variable for java.

Open powershell and type in:

```
java -version
```

if it doesn't give you any information, or gives the same error then follow the steps below to fix it.

Go to:

```
  Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> System
  Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables
```

For **JAVA_HOME** put in the path to the folder for java (not the bin or exe).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151
```

For **Path** append the path to the bin folder for java (not exe). Make sure you add a semicolon to the end of the previous path. It's used as a delimiter.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\
```

Comment: if you set the full path to wrapper.java.command and still can't start the service, reinstall the service

Answer (score 1):

Did you try starting the service as described in the docs? http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html  Section 2.2.